# Conditional formatting matching text based on another sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, match, conditional-formatting

I want to highlight text in cells in one column in one sheet that matches text in cells in a column in another sheet.
`=match(A1;B:B;0)>0` is working for columns within the same sheet, but `=match(A1;"Sheet2!B:B";0)>0` doesn't seem to do the trick for what I want.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use INDIRECT:

```
=MATCH(A1; INDIRECT("Sheet2!B:B"); 0)>0
```